# how to connect with grpc server with some metadata in python?

Tags: php, python, authentication, grpc

I need to connect a grpc server with some metadata ,such as username and password.From the grpc Docs，the PHP code is clear,I think this code will work:

```
$client = new Routeguide\RouteGuideClient('test.yintongzhibo.com:9002', [
'credentials' => Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createSsl(file_get_contents("xxx.pem")),
'update_metadata' => $metaProcessor,
'grpc.ssl_target_name_override' => 'test.yintongzhibo.com',]);

$metaProcessor = function($metadata,$client = []){
$values = $metadata;
$values[Username] = ['xxx'];
$values[Password] = ['yyy'];
return $values;}

list($resp,$status) = $client->getMarketData(request)->wait();
```

But I need to achieve the same thing in python.Python Docs is not very clear,so how to write the python code to do the same thing that the PHP code does?

Comment: anyone could help me please...it's very urgent ..I have searched for 2 days ..but there is no good result

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use `$values[username] = ['xxx'];$values[password] = ['yyy'];` with lowercase keys?

Answer (score 0):

Stubs have a metadata field.

Ex:
`stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'), metadata=[('key','value')])`

Comment: I trid this:stub.getMarketData(market_request,metadata=[('UserName','xxxx'),('Password','yyyy')]),but the error message is:"metadata was invalid:[('UserName','xxxx'),('Password','yyyy')]"...please help me..thanks very very much!there is my more detailed question url:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676398/how-to-use-python-to-authenticate-with-google-in-grpci-have-a-runable-php-code

Comment: And I tried this method:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071567/how-to-send-custom-header-metadata-with-python-grpc,like this:`myMetadata = (('username','xxxx'),('password','yyyy'))`,`stub.getMarketData(market_request,metadata=myMetadata)`,but the error meaasge is:not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Comment: It sounds like you have a different issue unrelated to gRPC.  The example you have provided should work.

Comment: but only when I add this code,there with be a error,I think the reason is this code may be not right.... could you give me some links to the api about this?I didn't find this in grpc Docs..thanks again

Comment: https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable ```__call__``` is the relevant function.